BIRT Page break using script
I am using BIRT 4.0 I have a table with 2 columns. I would like to do a page break if column A = 'TEXT'. What script format do I need and where do I insert it ?
The table is populated via an Oracle SQL select statement.
I have not done scripting in the past so I'm not sure what to try or where to start.
